# NullPointerException when setting the text of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, nullpointerexception, textview

I am trying iterate through a map of values and set text of a predefined layout to the values of the map.
I am getting a NullPointerException after the first iteration over the map and I am not sure why.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Fragment**

```
    Set keys = pairedValues.keySet();

    View summaryCell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_list_cell, null);

    cellTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.summaryListItemTitle);
    cellText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.summaryListItemText);

    for(Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String key = (String) i.next();

        switch(key) {
            case "eventCode": cellTitle.setText("Event Code");
                cellText.setText(pairedValues.get(key).second);
                break;
            case "accountId": cellTitle.setText(pairedValues.get(key).first);
                cellText.setText(pairedValues.get(key).second);
                break;
        }

        linearLayout.addView(summaryCell);

    }
```

**Layout**
This snippet is inside a RelativeLayout with a whole load of other stuff.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/summaryScrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/summaryFragback"
    android:layout_above="@+id/summarySaveEventButton">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/summaryFragback"
        android:id="@+id/summaryVerticalView"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/summarySaveEventButton">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Predefined layout being added to the LinearLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/summaryListItemTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@color/Dark_Background"
    android:id="@+id/summaryListItemText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/summaryListItemTitle"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/summaryListItemTitle"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/summaryListItemTitle" />
```

And (last but not least) the LogCat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.koodoocreative.isnapshot.fragments.SummaryFragment.onCreateView(SummaryFragment.java:79)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-17 18:33:47.571 6527-6527/com.koodoocreative.isnapshot E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Change 
View summaryCell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_list_cell, null);
to
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_list_cell, null);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you get your View like so:

```
View summaryCell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary_list_cell, null);
```

The you must use **that one** (`summaryCell`) to retrieve its children:

```
cellTitle = (TextView) summaryCell.findViewById(R.id.summaryListItemTitle);
cellText = (TextView) summaryCell.findViewById(R.id.summaryListItemText);
```

Comment: Thanks i will give this a go and mark as the correct answer if it works... Would of thought that would have come straight away to me but I had been staring at it for several hours wondering why it didnt work Cheers! **Edit:** Worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: It happens. You stare at a code for hours and don't see the evident error. Then a freshcomer arrives and tells you: "Hey! It's under your nose!" And you feel like an idiot. It just happens. ;)